# Get a list of SQL scripts that ran on my server

Tags: sql-server

The schema change history report tells me when the schema of a DB was last changed.

I would have run an *x.sql* file on that same DB for those changes to have happened. Does SQL Server log that I ran *x.sql* on 3/01/2016 at 3:15?

Comment: Check the table in which you inserted the data, if it is there you did it. If you have trigger on table that would fire upon this insert operation and can collect information for you but this would definitely have some performance impact.

Comment: Are you asking to check that your code is the latest version (e.g. you've installed the latest revision of a stored proc)? Or is this to do with whether you've inserted data into the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it doesn't.  SQL Server doesn't really have any concept of script files, it just processes commands that are run against it.

You could potentially set up some kind of automated process and/or tracing to track this, maybe setting the application name to the name of the script and tracing that but there's nothing in the box that I'm aware of which will do this automatically.